# Why is my function continuing even after I give it wrong input?

Tags: c++

I made up a game called password hacker in C++, purpose is to guess the password through given hints, when I input the correct password, it works correct, and moves to the new level as well.

But it does the same even when I input wrong password as well.

```
#include <iostream>

void Intro(int Level) {
  std::cout << "SUP, this PC is locked\n\n" << "well, sure why not give it a try.... it will all be over soon when you type the password incorrectly.\n" << "type your best code here to break security of server number " << Level;
}
bool PlayGame(int Diff) {
  Intro(Diff);

  int CodeA = 0;
  int CodeB = 1;
  int CodeC = 2;

  int CodeProduct = CodeA * CodeB * CodeC;
  int CodeSum = CodeA + CodeB + CodeC;

  std::cout << std::endl;

  //Instructions
  std::cout << "+ 3 number password" << "\n+The numbers adds up to " << CodeSum << "\n+The numbers multiply up to " << CodeProduct << std::endl;

  int PlayerGuessA;
  int PlayerGuessB;
  int PlayerGuessC;

  std::cin >> PlayerGuessA >> PlayerGuessB >> PlayerGuessC;

  int PlayerSum = PlayerGuessA + PlayerGuessB + PlayerGuessC;
  int PlayerProduct = PlayerGuessA * PlayerGuessB * PlayerGuessC;
  std::cout << "You entered:\n" << PlayerGuessA << " " << PlayerGuessB << " " << PlayerGuessC;

  std::cout << "\n \n Your numbers multiply up to: " << PlayerProduct;
  std::cout << "\n Your numbers add up to: " << PlayerSum;

  if (PlayerSum != CodeSum && PlayerProduct != CodeProduct) {
    std::cout << std::endl << "Like i said earlier, PATHETIC" << std::endl;
    return false;

  } else {
    std::cout << std::endl << "Well, No shit Sherlock " << std::endl;
    return true;
  }

}

int main() {
  int Lev = 1;
  while (true) {
    bool bLevelComplete = PlayGame(Lev);
    std::cin.clear(); //clears any errors
    std::cin.ignore(); //discards buffer
    ++Lev;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because your code doesn't use the password entered is correct to determie whether the loop should be continued. What is your *expected* behavior?

Comment: You get the return from your function `bool bLevelComplete= PlayGame(Lev)` but instead of `while (!bLevelComplete)` or something like that you simply have `while (true)`

Comment: FYI, you are allowed to use multiple lines for a `cout` statement.  I recommend one `<<` per line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me like you need to put your level up code within your win condition statement, otherwise you're telling the game to keep going regardless of the outcome.

So make Lev global, take the ++Lev out of the main function and put it in the else statement of PlayGame.

OR

Have an if statement wrapped around the ++Lev that takes the return value of PlayGame as it condition. So,

```
if(bLevelComplete){
    ++Lev;
}
```